# What do I need to escape for strings in DuckDB

Tags: sql, duckdb

Which characters need to be escaped to properly escape a string for a DuckDB SQL statement? I've searched but I can't find a standard grammar for SQL strings, and even if I could I don't know if DuckDB follows it exactly.

Comment: Give an example of you what you mean.

Comment: I have an arbitrary string. What characters in it do I need to escape to use it in a DuckDB SQL statement where you could use a string literal? The naive answer is "replace every single quote with two single quotes" but I am unsure if that is sufficient.

Comment: That's about it. If needed, you can use chr() function to include tricky characters. `'Hello ' || chr(1234) || ' village!'`.

Comment: Do you have a reference?

Comment: You don't escape, you use proper parameterized queries.

Comment: Of course I know about parameterized queries. They are not always a possibility.

Comment: How are the listed questions duplicates? One is about PostgreSQL not DuckDB. One is about escaping Vs parametrisation. I did not ask about either of those. Smh guys.

Answer (score 2):

I read the source code. DuckDB actually uses PostgreSQL's SQL parser. PostgreSQL's behaviour is [specified here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS). It supports strings with C-style escapes as an extension (`E'foo\nbar'`) but by default you only need to replace single quotes with two single quotes.

Comment: It's fully safe to use parameterized queries. Escaping characters is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't use parameterised queries everywhere. E.g. for `... FROM 'foo.json'`.

Comment: No, you can't since parameters take place of scalar values. To dynamically change the table name (what's the use case for this again?) you can use Dynamic SQL. However, that opend the door wide open to SQL Injection, if not done properly.

Comment: Yep you've got it now. I don't understand your use case question. It's for making `'foo.json'` a runtime parameter.